# Remove all user permissions, including individual permissions, and restore them after maintenance

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sharepoint-permissions, modern-team-site, maintenance

I'm using SharePointOnline's Modern UI.

I'd like to remove all user permissions for our maintenance.

However, there are individual permissions that do not inherit the permissions of the site, so it does not seem easy to do.

OOTB maintenance mode cannot be used because even the backend cannot be updated.

Is there a way to control the permissions of all users at once, including permissions that do not inherit site permissions?
I want to put it back when the maintenance is over.

I am very grateful for any ideas.

Comment: what kind of maintenance are you performing on the site? will you need write access during this time or are you just updating web parts via the app catalog?

Comment: @CallumCrowley I want to update many list items by PowerAutomate.And replace some Flows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think controlling permission and adding back would be right or easy way....

Alternately You can make Site Read only for your maintenance period. Try below PowerShell

```
$AdminCenterURL="https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com" 
$SiteURL = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing" 
#Connect to SharePoint Online 
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential) 
#PowerShell to set sharepoint online site to read only 
Set-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -LockState ReadOnly
```

Comment: I know how to make it Read only, but we want the admin to update the data during 
maintenance.